# How to sub to and monitor a VerneMQ cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, mqtt-vernemq

I managed to create a cluster of 2 Vernemq nodes.

Both are well communicating and are located to a different server, respectively

- A.company.com
- B.company.com

Following command shows both nodes running. (ssl and port 8883 are used)

```
vmq-admin cluster show
+-----------------------+-------+
|        Node           |Running|
+-----------------------+-------+
|ServerAMQ@10.107.1.25  | true  |
|ServerBMQ@10.107.1.26  | true  |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

Everything is running fine actually, eg :

```
mosquitto_pub -h a.mycompany.com -p 8883 -t 'topic/A/1' -m "foo" -d --cert client.crt --key client.key --cafile ca.crt -d
```

---

As i'm subbing **A.mycompany.com**, does the Cluster distribute to **B.mycompany.com** ?

Can please someone share some insight on how it works ?

---

As i don't have any experience on this subject, may i please ask you which is the best way to supervise cluster's activity ?

1. Graphite (i saw some cluster's related metrics)
2. http://(oneofthetwoserver):8888/metrics

Regards,

Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to overview the cluster is: http://{{your_server}}:8888/status.

For a production deployment, I'd use Prometheus metrics in any case.

I'm not sure I get your question regarding broker A and B. If they are clustered, messages published to A will be delivered to a subscriber on broker B, provided the topic subscription matches.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. I'll give a shot with Prometheus.

No doubt my question about cluster is a beginner's question, thus really poorly worded.
Client are coded with Python actually, and connection are made using A.mycompany.com. Should i leave as it is or should i give the possibility to randomly sub to A.mycompany.com or to B.mycompany.com ?

Comment: You would probably prefer to load balance the subscriptions (randomly or stickingly) over the cluster nodes. For that you'd need, well, a load balancer in front of the cluster.